# Certificate pinning for websockets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, firefox, websocket

How do I enable certificate pinning for websockets?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Public_Key_Pinning provides details on certificate pinning for HTTPS traffic. If I include the same header for websocket, would the pinning work or if I have HTTPS pinning enabled, websocket pinning is enabled by default?